# Simplifying expression with absolute value

Tags: real-analysis

I've come across a past exam paper question, which I have the solutions to, which I have understood until the third part of it. I'll do my best to explain it without writing out the entire question.

> Define a sequence by $\left ( a_{n} \right )_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by $$a_{1} = 1, $$
>   $$a_{n+1} = 1/(1+a_{n}). $$
>
> (c) Use the quadratic equation you've found in (b) to show that $$\left | a_{n+1} - \alpha \right |\leq \alpha \left | a_{n}-\alpha  \right |,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

The quadratic equation is $\alpha =\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

In the solutions it states:

> |$a_{n}-\alpha|=|\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}-\alpha|=|\frac{1-\alpha-\alpha a_{n}}{1+a_{n}}|$

But I don't understand where the $\alpha a_{n}$ came from. This is directly followed by:

> $≤|1-\alpha-\alpha a_{n}|=|\alpha^{2}-\alpha a_{n}|$

in which I don't understand how these are equal. Any help, or advice, would be much appreciated.

Comment: here i'm missing somthing, this is not an equation but a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+a_n}.$$  Hence $$\left|a_{n+1} - \alpha\right| = \left| \frac{1}{1+a_n} - \alpha \right| = \left| \frac{1}{1+a_n} - \frac{\alpha(1+a_n)}{1+a_n} \right| = \left| \frac{1 - \alpha - \alpha a_n}{1+a_n} \right|.$$  Then since $a_n \ge 0$, $1+a_n \ge 1$, meaning that $$\frac{|1 - \alpha - \alpha a_n|}{|1+a_n|} \le \left|1 - \alpha - \alpha a_n\right|.$$  Then if $\alpha = (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$, it easily follows by direct calculation that $\alpha^2 = 1 - \alpha$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.